# Filling and printing Array of Structs

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, struct

my program is supposed to fill an array of structs and eventually sort them. My problem that I'm running into is when I fill it and try to print it, it's printing out things that weren't inputted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct bankaccount
 {
        int number;
        //string name;
        int money;
 };

int main()
 {
        int i;
        bankaccount bank[10];
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
          cin >> bank[i].number >> bank[i].money;
         // getline(cin, bank[i].name);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
          cout << bank[i].number << " " << bank[i].money << endl;
        }
 }
```

And I'm inputting with a data file.

```
4 5024.24
3 2234.23
2 4332.21
1 4567.32
8 2345.32
5 2233.56
9 9008.98
10 9430.23
6 4560.29
7 8384.08
```

And when I run it by typing cat data | sortingarray.cpp, it gives me the weird output:

```
4 5024
0 1
-1469612912 32767
4197157 0
2 0
4197261 0
952461936 32593
4197168 0
0 0
4196608 0
```

in which only the first line is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define data member `money` as having type `double`

```
struct bankaccount
{
        int number;
        //string name;
        double money;
};
```

Otherwise an error occurs when you are trying to enter an integer and the input buffer of the stream contains a dot. It is not a valid symbol for integer number representations.

Comment: Well that's kind of embarrassing, I didn't notice that I declared money as an int! It works now, however I'm trying to add names to the struct and when I use the names, it'll only print out the first line correctly. Do you think you could help me with that?